# Searching array for item. How to display position item was found at?

Tags: java, arrays

I am creating an application in BlueJ that allows the user to sort and search an unordered array. I have the search working. At present it asks the user to input a number to search the array for and returns found or not found which is fine.

I would like to be able to tell the user what position in the array that the number was found?

Below is my code for me search method:

```
    public static void dosearch(OArray a)
    {
        clrscr();            
        if ( a.isEmpty() ) {
            System.out.println("Array is Empty!");
            pressKey();
            return;
        }
        clrscr();
        System.out.println("Enter number to search for : ");
        int item;
        item = Genio.getInteger();
        if ( a.retrieve(item) == false )
            System.out.println("Cannot find " + item);
        else
            System.out.println(item + " Found");
        pressKey();
    }
```

OArray Class code:

```
    public class OArray extends Array
    {
// These are the Fields

// Constructor
public OArray(){   
    super();
    System.out.println("OArray Created!!! size 10");                
}

public OArray(int newsize){       
    super(newsize);
    System.out.println("OArray Created!!!");                
}


public boolean addToEnd(int item)
{
    if ( isFull() == true )
        return false;

    array[nextfree]=item;
    nextfree++;
    //bubbleSort();
    return true;
}       



public void bubbleSort()
{
    int temp = 0;boolean swaps = true;int last = nextfree-1;int i = 0;

    while (swaps == true )
    {
        swaps=false;
        i = 0;
        while (i < last)
        {
            if (array[i] > array[i+1])
            {
                temp = array[i+1];
                array[i+1] = array[i];
                array[i] = temp;
                swaps=true;
            }
            i++;
        }             
    }                        
}


public boolean retrieve(int item)
{                 
     if ( isEmpty() )
        return false;                        
    int i=0;
    while ( i < nextfree )
    {
        if ( array[i] >= item )
        {
            posfound=i;
            if ( item == array[i] )
            {
                itemback = item;
                posfound = i;
                return true;
            }
            else return false;
        }
        i++;            
    }
    posfound = nextfree;        
    return false;        
}   

public boolean addToFront(int item)
{
    return addToEnd(item);
}
```

Comment: You're using a non-standard API. We don't have any idea what OArray is. All we can says is thus: read its API documentation.

Comment: I was wondering what an OArray is, couldn't find in google.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this. OArray is the class that contains some methods that the array uses. The menu class that contains the code that I posted, inherits the methods in the OArray class. Does that make any sense? Apologies.

Comment: It makes sense, but we can't tell you how to use a class if all we know about it is its name. We needs its source code or its documentation.

Comment: Sigh!!  Just have `retrieve` return -1 for "not found" and the array index if found.

Comment: Hi. Please remember that I am completely new to this and learning. Could you explain more about the retrieve and how to use this in my dosearch method? Thank you.

Comment: @AdamBatkin explained it in his answer. Read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the only way to access an item in an array is by index, so knowing the index is easy, since you already know it. The traditional idiom is that you have some sort of `find()` method which returns the index of the element if it is found, or `-1` otherwise.

```
int[] a = new int[] { 7, 2, 4, 6 };
int foundAt = findItemInArray(a, 2);
if (foundAt >= 0) {
    System.out.println("Found at [" + foundAt + "]");
} else {
    System.out.println("Not found");
}

public static int findItemInArray(int[] a, int lookingFor) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] == lookingFor) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the linear search method.
Once you have found the number in the for loop store it's index there and then. You can display it later.

Comment: This is not a full solution. This could be a comment only. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: Ok i will remove it